# QMap strange behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

After inizialized a QMap in the .h file in this way

```
QMap<QString, QString> *map;
```

When I declare in the constructor

```
map = new QMap<QString, QString>;
map["one"] = "foobar";
```

error: invalid types 'QMap*[const char [4]]' for array subscript
     map["one"] = "foobar";
             ^

Where is the problem?

Comment: try it with a star in front of map (the pointer star *)

Answer (score 1):

You need to dereference the `map` pointer.

```
map = new QMap<QString, QString>;
map["one"] = "foobar";
```

Should be:

```
map = new QMap<QString, QString>;
(*map)["one"] = "foobar";
```

This is because `map` is a pointer to an object; `*map` returns a reference to the object.

The compiler error message is not very helpful, because the compiler assumes that for a pointer `p`, `p[expr]` is an [array subscript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th52k9c8.aspx) operation.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is a pointer. Pointers happen to have a built-in `operator[]`, which is why the error message may appear a bit strange at first glance. It has nothing to do with `QMaps`'s overloaded `operator[]`, actually.

Consider this:

```
int array[123];
array["one"] = "foobar";
```

It will produce the same error:

```
error: invalid types ‘int [123][const char [4]]’ for array subscript
 array["one"] = "foobar";
```

To get to the pointed-to-type (`QMap` in this case), you have to dereference the pointer: `*map`.

It will then work fine:

```
(*map)["one"] = "foobar";
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others says you must dereference the map if you create in that way. But if you create your map on stack instead of on the heap (remove the *) than it will be easier.

In your header file:

```
QMap< QString, QString > map;
```

In your source file (remove the line with the `new` keyword):

```
map[ "one" ] = "foobar";
```